# Doing header with columns

Tags: java, list, netbeans

can someone explain me why this line of code:

```
System.out.printf("%-6s", "Num", "%-10s", "Nome", "%-18s", "Idade Automóvel", "%-15s", "Total de Prémios");
```

Does this:

```
Num
```

Instead of this:

```
Num    Nome     Idade Automóvel     Total de Prémios
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only first argument represents formatting all other arguments are just data to be used in places as speciffied with format string. You should write it like this:

```
System.out.printf("%-6s %-10s %-18s %-15s", "Num", "Nome", "Idade Automóvel", "Total de Prémios");
```